# cocos2d-x (3.3) プロジェクトをAndroid Studioで開発する方法

Tags: android, java, android-studio, eclipse, cocos2d-x

cocos2d-x (3.3) がプロジェクトを新規作成した際に、生成されるproj.androidフォルダがあります。
現在は、Eclipseでの開発が主流と思っていますが、Android Studioで開発できるようにすることは可能でしょうか？

"設定ファイルを追加"や、"Eclipseからの変換"などの方法や、参考サイトの情報など有りましたら合わせて、アドバイス/情報を頂きたいです。

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: [tag:cocos2d-x]タグを追加しました。タグは質問[edit]フォームのタグ入力欄から新規追加できます。← 失礼しました。ちょっと正確ではありません: パブリックベータからは、タグを新規追加するには信用度が150必要になります。

Comment: タグが見つけれなくて、どのタグを付けるべきか迷ってました。
ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Android Studio は、Eclipse 用の形式のプロジェクトを Android Studio 用に変換する
機能を持っているので変換すればビルド自体はできるかもしれません。
自動変換がうまく行かなくても、NDK を使ったビルドの構成自体は作ることは可能です
(build.gradle を手動でいじることにはなりますが)。

ただし。現状の Android Studio は C++ のコードのビルドをする機能はあってもコーディングを
サポートする機能はほとんどありません。

このような状態なので開発自体は不可能ではないですが、cocos2d-x の開発環境として
採用するにはまだ早いのではないかなというのが正直な感想です。

一応 NDK を使う場合の構成方法についても書いておきます。
基本は、 src/main/jni/ の下に、 *.cpp や *.h を置くだけです。
今まで .mk ファイルで行っていたような設定は、以下の様な感じで build.gradle に記述します。

```
android {
    ...
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        ndk {
            moduleName "native_library"
            stl "gnustl_shared"
            abiFilters 'all'
            //abiFilters 'armeabi', 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a', 'x86', 'x86_64', 'mips', 'mips64'
            ldLibs "log"
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

上記の方法は 標準のやりかたですが、今までのように、 ndk-build コマンドを実行するように構成することも可能です(いろいろ記述が必要になりますが)。